# Laravel pagination json format

Tags: json, laravel, pagination

I am using laravel database pagination for an api. It gives the output as follows :

```
{
    "current_page": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Default"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Default without Sidebar"
        }
    ],
    "first_page_url": "http://example.com/api/layouts?a=1",
    "from": 1,
    "last_page": 1,
    "last_page_url": "http://example.com/api/layouts?a=1",
    "next_page_url": null,
    "path": "http://example.com/api/layouts",
    "per_page": 10,
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "to": 2,
    "total": 2
}
```

I don't want or need `first_page_url`, `last_page_url`, etc, so it should just be:

```
{
    "current_page": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Default"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Default without Sidebar"
        }
    ],
    "from": 1,
    "last_page": 1,
    "to": 2,
    "total": 2
}
```

So, Is there a way, to format the output json so that i can remove or hide some extra info which i don't need .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$except = ['first_page_url', 'last_page_url'];
return array_except(<YourModel>::paginate(...)->toArray(), $except);
```